# The selected tab button in "Upcoming Stack Overflow Events" has an ugly color

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, dark-mode

I think the color of this button should be changed in dark mode because it is unreadable:

[image: Wrong color]

---

---

Second thing I noticed:

When you click / pass the mouse on these buttons, the color is the same as in Normal mode:

[image: Wrong color - again]

Comment: This is not only a very important page for anyone dreaming of the [Not a Robot](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot) badge, but I think one may even meet [Community ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) at such an event :) I've been meaning to ask them why they ate my post.

Comment: Even if Community ♦ [**got the badge**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot?userid=-1)

Comment: This is already known and has been reported numerous times. Please see [Dark Mode Beta - help us root out low-contrast and un-converted bits](/q/395949/4642212) and search for tab related entries. The Linked section also includes several reports about tabs.

Comment: @D_00 - as already mentioned by Sebastian, it was reported before (actually, twice - there is a separate post - I will link to it if I find it again). Give it 6 to 8 weeks to be fixed... The biggest issue is that this page uses old components - so until SE decides to rework the whole thing, we will have do with user styles / userscripts :)

Comment: Closing this as a duplicate wouldn't be helpful. Yes, the problem is the same, but the location is completely different, so it's easier for us to keep track of what still needs fixing separately.

Comment: @AdamLear - not sure if that's not helpful - the root cause is the same, right? And the question is not going to go anywhere. Now they are linked, I don't think anyone here meant "reported before" as an accusation - just as a pointer.

Comment: @OlegValter I'm sure that it's not helpful. :) We don't typically look at "what questions are closed as a duplicate of this one" when it comes to bug reports, and in this specific case the fix is likely going to be the same but it does need to happen in two different places.

Comment: @AdamLear - well, it was closed in the meantime :) But If you need it open to track - not gonna protest, it's not like the target has answers anyway. Can this be considered as a confirmation that this is at least in the sights of the team? I understand this should be a lot of work, but 'tis the third time it's being reported, so a [status-review] would at least bring the minds of reporters at ease.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've resolved this issue and fixed a number of other similar issues with the same outdated component in the process. Thanks for the report. The fix will be merged in today or tomorrow.